# Why I receive SQLITE_ERROR with example provided on Sequelize web page?

Tags: sqlite, sequelize.js

I started to develop with provided example
https://sequelize.org

But I got an error:
"SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: Users"

```js
import { DataTypes, Sequelize } from "sequelize";
const main5 = async () => {
    const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:');
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        username: DataTypes.STRING,
        birthday: DataTypes.DATE,
    });
    const jane = await User.create({
        username: 'janedoe',
        birthday: new Date(1980, 6, 20),
    });
    const users = await User.findAll();
    console.log(users.map((u) => ({...u})));
}
main5().catch(console.error);
```

How to make that work? Why it doesn't work out of the box? What is wrong here?

EDIT:
Thx @Anatoly, I should use

```js
await sequelize.sync();
// or
await User.sync();
```

Comment: If you didn't create `Users` table beforehand you should call `await User.sync()` before calling any `User` methods that interact with DB in order to create the Users table.